# Error al hacer condicional Char en lenguaje C

Tags: c, dev-c++

Tengo un problema al intentar realizar una condicional con un string, lo que intento es primero preguntar la cuidad y dependiendo de lo que el usuario escriba me realice la condicional que tengo en el codigo, pero no me funciona me lleva directamente al `else`

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main (){
    char ciudad[0];

    printf("Digite el nombre de una ciudad: ");
    scanf("%s",&ciudad);

if (ciudad == "medellin"){
    printf("En este momento en %s esta lloviendo",ciudad);
}else if (ciudad == "bucaramanga"){
    printf("En este momento en %s esta haiendo un dia caluroso",ciudad);
}else{
    printf("%s no esta en nuestra base de datos",ciudad);
}

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La comparación de Strings debes realizarla mediante el método [strcmp()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (){
    char ciudad[0];

    printf("Digite el nombre de una ciudad: ");
    scanf("%s",&ciudad);

//if (ciudad == "medellin"){    
if (strcmp(ciudad, "medellin") == 0){
    printf("En este momento en %s esta lloviendo",ciudad);
//}else if (ciudad == "bucaramanga"){
}else if (strcmp(ciudad, "bucaramanga") == 0) {
    printf("En este momento en %s esta haiendo un dia caluroso",ciudad);
}else{
    printf("%s no esta en nuestra base de datos",ciudad);
}

    return 0;
}
```

---

> **int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );**
>
> - Si el valor de retorno es <0 indica que el primer carácter que no coincide tiene un valor inferior en str1 que en str2
> - **Si el valor de retorno es igual a 0 indica que ambas cadenas son iguales (str1 == str2)**.
> - Si el valor de retorno es >0 indica el primer carácter que no coincide tiene un mayor valor en str1 que en str2